# How to change height and tooltip width for JS library highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graphics, highcharts

### I have highcharts library for JavaScript how to change height and tooltip width ?

```
tooltip: {
                    backgroundColor:"#B4F2D6",
                    useHTML:true,
                    crosshairs: true
                },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you allow useHTML on your highcharts, you can add some css properties!

```
.highcharts-tooltip>span {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
}
```

In addition take a look at this :

**[A JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9oq896qs/)**